# SVG gets distorted

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, svg

I'm trying to embed several .svg-files on my website. 
Everything seems to work perfectly fine as long as I use Chrome, Firefox or any Mobile browser I've tested so far. However, there's one exception: Whenever I view a svg on my Windows Phone (Internet Explorer Mobile) the image gets distorted.

I guess I found the reason for this behavior already: Since I want the size of any svg to be fluid, I gave them a percentage-based width and an auto-height. This works, as mentioned before, fine for most browser. Internet-Explorer however, seems to ignore height:auto thereby stretching the svg to it's maximum heigth.

That said, one solution would be to assign fixed dimensions for every single .svg. 
But that would sacrifice the idea of a responsive design.

Has anybody an idea what the problem might be?

Oh, an here's the link to a page of my website featuring a svg (the black "star" saying "select"):

http://alexanderschlosser.de/select.html

Many thanks in advance!
Alex

EDIT: That's the code of one of the embedded SVGs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.4, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="90px" height="90px" viewBox="0 0 90 90" enable-background="new 0 0 90 90" xml:space="preserve">
<path fill="#E64132" d="M45,87.25C21.703,87.25,2.75,68.297,2.75,45S21.703,2.75,45,2.75S87.25,21.703,87.25,45
    S68.297,87.25,45,87.25"/>
<path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M45,5.5c21.78,0,39.5,17.72,39.5,39.5c0,21.78-17.72,39.5-39.5,39.5C23.22,84.5,5.5,66.78,5.5,45
    C5.5,23.22,23.22,5.5,45,5.5 M45,0C20.147,0,0,20.147,0,45c0,24.853,20.147,45,45,45c24.853,0,45-20.147,45-45
    C90,20.147,69.853,0,45,0"/>
<path fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="5.5" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M67.08,45c0,0-7.193-13.292-22.08-13.292
    S22.92,45,22.92,45S30.113,58.292,45,58.292S67.08,45,67.08,45z"/>
<path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M50.433,45c0-3-2.433-5.433-5.433-5.433c-3,0-5.432,2.433-5.432,5.433S42,50.433,45,50.433
    C48,50.433,50.433,48,50.433,45"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: What version of iemobile? and you might want to include how you have the main base setup of the svg (code)

Comment: My phone is running Windows Explorer 10. 
I create the SVGs using Adobe Illustrator CS6.
Export options are:
SVG 1.1 with embedded images.

I will copy the code in my previous post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to have some responsive SVG's add this new attribute to the svg tag:

`preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"`  <----- take notice of the capitalization

you dont need the width and height attributes anymore, they should now responsively conform to the size of the container they are in  (though you might need to define the size of the container because sometimes chrome will render extra white space below an svg if not defined).

edit: defining the width and height of the svg in css works too

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L5m27/)

Comment: Yes! This works! Thank you so much.

Actually, I had to delete both height and width attributes – but now it just looks perfectly fine on my phone, too.

Thanks again!

Comment: @alex no problem.  I recently had to learn a whole bunch of svg goodness.  I use it everywhere now.  Have fun :)